# port unity game to facebook canvas platform using parse

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas

I am porting a unity game to facebook canvas to make it available on facebook by using following link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas

I am using parse to deploy my game.
I am successfully able to deploy my game and if i navigate to that url I am able to download my uploaded game files.

when I gave that url as Secure Canvas URL , it showed there is no file on that parse url.

it is because Facebook Canvas applications makes HTTP POST requests to your canvas URL. Parse Hosting only supports HTTP GET for static HTML pages. 
I got that I have to add some code, but cant understand which code to add and where to add, as I am not a much web person.

any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I am aware of is that facebook requires https:// connection and it does not support http:// while parse is http://

You will be able to see this info if you go to your facebook app canvas page with google chrome. Then hit F12 or right-click > inspect. The console will have the error log.

What you need is an https hosting

Comment: on that article they have recommended parse. and in inspect element it shows nothing just an internal error

Comment: https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-hosting-post-requests-management-error-facebook-page-tabs    I got this link and it have code but cant understand where to add code and what changes i have to make in this code

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of the 'express' module (i'm not a web guy either). You need to write server-side code in app's Cloud Code section.
you can find all the info [HERE](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/building-parse-web-apps-with-the-express-web-framework/)